# Generating POJOs for RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, web, service

We generate POJO from WSDL/XSD in SOAP services. How do we generate POJOs while consuming  RESTful web service?

Comment: Does that REST service publish a service descriptor in WSDL or WADL? (Some do, some don't…)

Comment: It does not. How to generate pojos for such services?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no WSDL or WADL for the service (a relatively common situation) you're going to have to do this the hard way.

One possible way *if the service takes XML* is to write and XSD that describes the documents that it takes and returns. This isn't too hard if you've ever written XSD before and you use an editor designed to assist this sort of thing (I use the one in Eclipse, but there are many others). Otherwise, just write the POJOs yourself. I advise keeping such POJOs *very* simple, possibly with no methods at all and just public fields and annotations. The main annotations to be aware of are:

- `@XmlRootElement` — these name the elements that will form the outside of a message going in either direction. Goes on a class.
- `@XmlElement` — marks a field for mapping as a sub-element of a message.
- `@XmlAttribute` — marks a field for mapping as an attribute.
- `@XmlType` — marks a class as suitable for use as the type of a compound element of another message.

There are many more, but the best thing to do is to write some POJOs and try using them:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Example {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String pqr;
    @XmlElement
    public String abc;
    @XmlElement
    public List<String> def = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

```
Example example = new Example();
example.abc = "oscar";
example.def.add("bert");
example.def.add("ernie");
// Omitting the attribute; null maps to absence/optionality

JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.class);
Marshaller m = c.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(example, System.out);
```

The reverse direction is unmarshalling (with a JAXB `Unmarshaller`, of course) and is pretty similar.

To use JSON instead of XML, use the Jettison library [as outlined in this blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html). (In essence, you're just putting a special writer/reader of DOM trees in between the JSON and JAXB.)